# Update a List of KeyValue pair

Tags: c#, linq

I have a WPF application where I need to implement this concept:

There is a `combobox` and a `datagrid`. The `combobox` holds a list of sellers, and the datagrid holds the rates of items they sell.

I want something like this:

```
client -> null

item    |   rate
--------------------
itemA   |   0.00
itemB   |   0.00
itemC   |   0.00
```

When none of the `client` (seller) is selected, all the rates of `items` default to 0.00.

Now, let's say I choose a `client` by name of `clientA`, who does not sell `ItemB`. Then, the display should reflect this.

```
client -> clientA

item    |   rate
--------------------
itemA   |   5.00
itemB   |   0.00
itemC   |   8.00
```

Basically, it should show 0.00 instead of `null` for the `items` a `client` does not sell.

This is actually the work of a `Dictionary`, or in case of `WPF`, an `ObservableDictionary`.

But, I am using `Caliburn`, and I would like to solve it by using `BindableCollection`.

So, I have something similar to this:

```
if (SelectedReferenceClient == null)
{
    Rates = new BindableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>(itemrepository.FindWhere(c => true).Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>(key: c.Name, value: 0)));;
} //retrieve all items and put value to zero.

    var SelectedClientRates = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>(raterepository.FindWhere(c => c.Client == SelectedClient).Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>(key: c.ItemName, value: c.Rate)));
    //get rates of items they sell

    foreach (var a in SelectedClientRates)
    {
        var b = Rates.FirstOrDefault(c => c.key == a.key);
        b.value = a.value;
    }//update the values in BindingCollection
```

This might work, but it's noisy and it's kludgy. Is there any `LINQ` way to do this? As `LINQ` abhors side effects, my first thought was that it wasnt possible.

But, if I want to stick to `BindableCollection` and not use `ObservableDictionary`, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Do you really want to **update existing** `BindableCollection` instance, or creating a new instance would work for you?

Comment: Creating a new instance would work as well.

Comment: @IvanStoev, how should I create a new instance to get the job done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If creating a new `BindableCollection<T>` instance is an option (rather than updating the existing), you can build `IEnumerable<T>` query with LINQ and pass it to the `BindableCollection<T>` constructor overload accepting `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var keys = SelectedReferenceClient == null ? itemrepository.FindWhere(c => true).Select(c => c.Name) : Rates.Select(rate => rate.Key);
var rates = raterepository.FindWhere(c => c.Client == SelectedClient).Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>(key: c.ItemName, value: c.Rate));
var combined = from key in keys
               join rate in rates on key equals rate.Key into match
               from rate in match.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>(key: key, value: rate.Key != null ? rate.Value : 0);
Rates = new BindableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>(combined);
```

The LINQ part is a simple [left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_2) between 2 enumerables. The left enumerable contains all items and is obtained from either repository or the already populated storage, while the right enumerable contains the selected item/value pairs and is obtained from its repository with the corresponding filter.

Once the correlation is done by `left outer join` operator, the resulting value is determined from the presence/absence of the match - either the match value or 0. The only unusual  here is the check for match existence - normally we use something like `right != null`, but since here the `right` is a `struct` (value type), we use a string member of the struct for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

See sample code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string SelectedClient = "";
            List<RateRepository> raterepository = new List<RateRepository>();
            Dictionary<string, decimal> SelectedClientRates = raterepository.Where(c => c.Client == SelectedClient)
                .GroupBy(x => x.ItemName, y => y.Rate)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
    public class RateRepository
    {
        public string Client { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was trying to avoid `Dictionary` because binding and `Dictionary` doesn't work, unless I create `ObservableDictionary`.

Comment: And that code wont return the items the selected client does not sell.

Comment: Wait a second.  I just showed example how to get rid of your kludgy code.  Why don't you like ObservableDictionary?  You can always replace the .ToDictionary() with a .Select(x => new {.....}).ToList().